# Battery performance using wakelocks

Tags: android, wakelock, commonsware-cwac, powermanager

my app uses the commonsware wakeful pattern to wake the device up at a frequent (5 minute) repeating alarm interval. I know waking this frequently maybe the root of my problem, but the 
actual work done when the device wakes up is minimal and the code executes very fast. On a certain version of android (4.1.2) on certain devices (eg Xperia T), the app gets nailed in 
the Settings > Battery Use list as a high battery user. However, in all other versions/devices I've tested, the app doesn't make it into this list, even if I use a more agressive 
interval of 1 minute!

Is there a known bug around battery stats in 4.1.2? I can't find any related bug reports. From looking at the source code, I can see the wakelock gets released [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.2_r1/com/android/server/PowerManagerService.java#1052), but the battery stats get updated outside the wakelock [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.2_r1/com/android/server/PowerManagerService.java#1058). Is this a bug?

There seems to be a large amount of changes in the PowerManagerService's [current code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/commit/9630704ed3b265f008a8f64ec60a33cf9dcd3345#services/java/com/android/server/power/PowerManagerService.java), but just wondering was this bug fixed?

Anyone else experiencing this? Any ideas on how to poke the system to update its battery stats after the wakelock is released?

Dom

Answer (score 0):

The Battery Usage metrics are more or less an educated guess by the OS. They are not especially accurate, not nearly as much as the output would have you believe.

You might use `adb shell dumpsys power` to confirm that the `WakeLock` is being released as expected on devices that are giving you this report.